# Change some (i.e. not all) displayed text on current web page

Tags: javascript, html

In languages such as Java or GUI frameworks such as Qt for C++, it is possible to get a handle to some block of text (e.g. a label widget) the user cannot change, but which the program can modify based upon some condition being satisfied.  I'd like to be able to do the same thing on an HTML web page from within some JavaScript code.

For example, consider a web page for entering user credentials.  If the credentials are invalid, I'd like to display a message on the current web page without having to load a completely new page.

I've gotten it to work using an HTML text box or textarea, set to disabled, read only with some display style changes (via CSS).  Changes induce some JavScript code to run which may result in changes to the value field of these text boxes or textareas.  While this works okay, it just doesn't seem right.  Is there a more orthodox way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. There are a few libraries to handle this.

You may be asking for form validation. If so, try jQuery and jQuery's validate extension library: [demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/milk/)

Or you may be asking for a more generic-use observer pattern. If so, try one of the many MVVM/MVC libraries for JavaScript such as backbone.js or knockout.js (also ember, agility, angular, and spine): [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thomas/Yqk5A/)

edit: also note that if your need is just standard form validation, you can accomplish it in jQuery validate without any code to speak of - just add properties directly on the HTML elements themselves indicating what the validation rules are. Unfortunately, HTML5 data attributes weren't around when it was written, so you apply the validation rules as CSS classes.

edit 2: also note that jQuery validate out-of-the-box supports remote validation, such as the credentials or username-already-exists scenario: [demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/ajaxSubmit-intergration-demo.html) or [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote#options)

Comment: The validation extension along with the general approach depicted in the demo seem to fit the bill.  Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome! I made an educated guess at where you were headed with your question, functionally. I've been there before :)

Comment: I should also mention, it is generally good practice to handle all the validation you handle at the client at the server as well. So if you would display red-error text at the browser via JavaScript for mismatching passwords, generate the same red-error text via server code if mismatching passwords are received at the server. I know that's annoying to worry about, but some server technologies have some methods to make it so you only have to write the validation rule once and it works both places. It is more to prevent malicious requests nowadays than to handle sans-javascript browsers.

Comment: Thanks.  I was primarily interested in the mechanics of the UI, but you raise a good point which I'll keep in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery's `.submit()`, using this  you can Bind an event handler to the "submit" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.

Example:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
      if ($("input:first").val() == "correct") {
        $("span").text("Validated...").show();
        return true;
      }
      $("span").text("Not valid!").show().fadeOut(1000);
      return false;
    });
```

You can also use jQuery's `.toggle()` to show/hide any div.

Read this W3C article for better understanding of recommendation by W3, [Providing client-side validation and adding error text via the DOM](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/SCR32) (slightly outdated)

Answer (score 0):

You should try jQuery's `.change();`

Assuming your HTML input has an ID:

```
<input type='text' id='idOfTheField' name='email'>
```

You should try:

```
$('#idOfTheField').change(function(){

  //Do stuff with the value.
  //Wich is $('#idOfTheField').value() by the way.

});
```

To manipulate the data with a webserver, you have to perform an AJAX call, following:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "parse.php",
  data: {
      email:$('#idOfTheField').value()
  }
}).done(function() { 
  // Add the CSS class ".valid" that makes the text field green, for example.
  $('#idOfTheField').addClass("valid"); 
});
```

Comment: I guess I'm looking for a suitable HTML tag which I can use to identify the text I want to be able to change.  What it looks like you're suggesting assumes I already have the text tagged.  Am I missing something?

Comment: yes, you should have an 'id' field on the html. like this: <input type='text' id='idOfTheField'>

Comment: So, I've been using <textarea> and <input type="text" ...>  Is there a more suitable form element to use?  I haven't been able to find one on any of the tutorial pages I've read.

Comment: input is fine for single line entries.